# How to emulate Fn (function key) keypress in xte

Tags: command-line, xorg, scripts, xte

xte is part of the xautomation package. After hours of man page reading and looking for documentation or working examples, I still cannot get xte to emulate a <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> keypress.

```
xte 'keydown Meta_L' 'key F7' 'keyup Meta_L'
```

I've tried Meta_L, Meta_R, Multi_key, key F7, keydown F7 then keyup F7. No combination seems to work.

Any idea how I can emulate a combination key press with a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key from a command/script?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually very tricky or near impossible to use `xte` to simulate fn + f key keypresses, as the fn key itself does not register at all in `xev`, and very often the fn keys or fn combinations are not seen by the kernel like other normal keyboard keys.

**Summary**

I actually managed to setup three key combinations (fn + f1, fn + f2 and fn + f3), because pressing each of these combinations resulted in the kernel issuing its 'unknown key pressed...set keycodes' dialogue. This meant that I was able to set the keycodes, and then go to the keyboard shortcuts dialogue and see if a keysym was assigned, e.g. XF86Paste. If so, it was now possible to assign a program to launch from them and it was also now possible to use `xte` to issue the following command, which was the equivalent of pressing fn + f1 for me:

```
xte 'keydown XF86Paste' 'keyup XF86Paste'
```

It may be a pecularity of one of my laptops that I can set three of these fn combinations like normal multimedia keys as [shown here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys), but I'll explain the process anyway for you and the particular steps that I followed.

---

**Full Explanation**

You might not be able to set the keys, as usually you cannot, but two or three may be able to be set, as I found out. Press fn and each of the function keys in turn (f1-f12)  while looking at the kernel log:

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

If they are recognised, you will see a kernel scancode:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xa7 on isa0060/serio0).   
kernel: [22751.972058] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e027 <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Now, for example, you must set these key combinations up with the information given by the kernel- i.e use the kernel scancode and a keycode of your choice (preferably a high number so it doesn't interfere with anything else). See your current keycodes with `sudo dumpkeys | grep ^keycode`, as noted [in this useful Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys).)

It is clear that because fn is not recognised as a key, but only in combination with another key, the key combination fn + f3, for example, is treated in effect as a single key, and so can be set just like other single multimedia buttons:

```
sudo setkeycodes e027 135
```

The above command must be entered separately for each of the key combinations you want to set, and must be placed in `/etc/rc.local` (without the sudo prefix) if you want them loaded on startup.

Now, you must check if there has been an X keysym associated with your new keycodes by going to keyboard shortcuts and seeing if the key combination, for example fn + F1, can be set. If it can be, a keysym such as XF86Paste will appear and the shortcut can be set to launch any program you wish.

Now all you need to do to test this with `xte` is to note the keysym (e.g. XF86Paste) you saw in the keyboard shortcuts dialogue for a particular combination (eg. fn + f1), and enter the appropriate command:

```
xte 'keydown XF86Paste' 'keyup XF86Paste'
```

This is the equivalent of you pressing and depressing fn + f1.

If you have set a program to launch with the key combination (fn + f...) assocated with the keysym, then the `xte` event will launch that program and you will know that the setting has worked.

---

**Conclusion**

This is a way to set fn + Function key combinations, but it will only be possible for your laptop if the kernel recognises at least one of the combinations as an unknown, but settable key. Only fn +f1, fn +f2, and fn + f3 were settable for me, but it will differ for your computer. If you want to experiment with modifying the actions of your 'sleep' fn + function key button, see [this Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys), but it may not be completely up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the author(s) of xte have fixed/resolved this issue simply.

As a test, I bound the F7 key to the Audio Mute functionality, Then,

```
echo 'key F7' | xte
```

and confirmed that the F7 key was generated successfully, by xte.