# Special keyboard keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, vaio

I have a new laptop,

It has the icon for toggling the touchpad on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> so I would like to assign this shortcut, I have a working script, and I can assign the script to any other combination, but it appears that ubuntu does not pick up the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination? how can I correct this?

The other one is,
My laptop has three extra buttons, `Assist`, `Web`, and `Vaio`.

These map to `Help`, `Homepage`, and `nothing` respectively.

the Web button is working perfectly.
The assist button if I am setting up a keyboard shortcut for something it binds fine, but then pressing it does nothing?

The Vaio button seems to not be listened to much like the combination I posted above.
How can i correct the assist and Vaio buttons?

Comment: This issue is beyond me, but I will say I have had a similar issue with a Logitech k360 keyboard that I was unable to resolve.  Hitting many function keys simply didn't work, and when I tried to bind them manually, it would confuse ubuntu and behave as if I were hitting the super key at the same time as the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It will help to first learn how Ubuntu is currently interpreting each of those key presses. Can you please try the `xev` command shown in step 2 [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) and post the results?

Comment: My related answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103928/how-to-emulate-fn-function-key-keypress-in-xte) might help, as it is about setting up fn and other keys.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike modifiers such as Alt and Ctrl, pressing the Fn key is never communicated to the operating system. The key merely modifies the scancodes of other keys, so pressing Fn+Right would emulate an End key, even though it may not physically exist, but they are indistinguishable by the OS. This behaviour is controlled exclusively by the keyboard electronics and can therefore not be altered without messing with the circuitry or microcontroller.

you could assign the f1 key as a shortcut to the required control that FN+F1 usually gives you, but you would lose your help key as a result

As far as the special keys are concerned, you would have to confirm what type of keyboard, the OS is seeing yours as.  It may be an international with extended keys so that the OS sees the extra keys. What model of viao are you using?