# hardware settings gets reset on reboot

Tags: touchpad, wifi-hardware-switch

I don't use WIFI and touch-pad much, every time my laptop Lenovo Z50-70 starts I switch off WIFI and disable touchpad with hardware keys ( <kbd>Fn</kbd>+ XX). But these two settings gets reset on reboot and resume from suspend. How do I make these settings permanent until I toggle them?

Comment: Have you tried turning WiFi off with the switch in the menu bar and turning the touchpad off in Mouse settings? By the way, <kbd>fn</kbd> keys aren't hardware; they're software.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yeah i tried switching off wifi from menu bar but same problem as with the hardware keys

Comment: How about the mousepad? If you want, you could try following the instructions at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112968/automatically-disable-wifi-wireless-when-wired

Comment: I know it's for 11.10, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

For both, if you are sure you don't want to use them you may be able blacklist the drivers of those pieces of hardware so they are not loaded on boot - blacklisting drivers is explained in full [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules). To determine the driver of the WiFi use `lspci -k` or `lshw -C network`, and blacklist the WiFi's driver module (You may also be able to do this with the 'Additional Drivers' GUI).
The (rather big) flaw with this method is what happens when you find you *do* need those pieces of hardware (particularly without a touchpad). You should be able to reload the modules using `sudo modprobe MODULE` in [a TTY](https://askubuntu.com/q/66195/178596).
If you really never want to use that hardware, you could remove the driver packages, but this almost guarantees you will need them at a later date.
You could also use `rfkill` and run it on boot similar to the method [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/67758/178596).

For the touchpad this is more complicated with drivers, but you could use `xinput` to disable the touchpad:

```
xinput --disable ID
```

<sup>You can determine the ID of the touchpad from `xinput -list`</sup>

This might not work system-wide from `/etc/rc.local`, so instead you could use [`~/.profile`](https://askubuntu.com/a/270050/178596) so it disables the touchpad on login.

Another method may be to send the signal's the key's send, though this is probably very difficult as this probably is in the hardware not the software - [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103928/how-to-emulate-fn-function-key-keypress-in-xte) may help though.

Comment: I sometimes want to use them, so blacklisting is not a good idea